# Dynamically populate a checkbox list control

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I've been messing for several hours with the next scenario:

- Populate dynamically a checkbox list as the user type some text in textbox (some kind of autocompleteextender).

As I told you before, I've been messing for hours (almost a full day) and still can't find a correct approach. What I have on mind at first was using dynamicpopulate control and a webmethod but can't make it work. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

EDITED: What I'm trying to do its a kind of hotmail functionality. When you hit new email and then you hit "To:" button, it pops a little window.

Comment: Do you have a text box where users type a text and on each key stroke check box list gets created accordingly? How big is your lookup list?

Comment: I will perform a search into a users list (starting to search after 4 letters typed). Just as an autocompleteextender.

Comment: Ideally you should do it using jquery and ajax calls to some custom web service function that will do user lookup. You can then dynamically build unordered list of checkboxes. If you are planning to do it using postbacks it will be very slow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code:

First I created asmx web service called Lookup.asmx with this function:

```
[WebMethod]
public GetUsersResponse[] LoadUsers()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Users"] != null) 
    {
        return (List<GetUsersResponse>)HttpContext.Current.Session["Users"];
    }

    return new List<GetUsersResponse>();

}

[WebMethod]
public GetUsersResponse[] GetUsers(string query)
{
    var users = new List<string>
    {
        "Brad Pitt",
        "Brad Pitt2",
        "Brad Pitt3",
        "Angelina Jolie",
        "Jeniffer Aniston",
        "Tom Cruise",
        "Katie Holmes",
        "Tom Hanks",
        "Sean Pen",
        "Jude Law",
        "Bruce Willis"
    };

    var returnUsers = users.Where(s => s.ToLower().Trim().StartsWith(query.ToLower().Trim()))
                     .Select(s => new GetUsersResponce { Name = s })
                     .ToArray();

    HttpContext.Current.Session["Users"] = returnUsers;
    HttpContext.Current.Session["Query"] = query;
    return returnUsers;
}

public class GetUsersResponse
{
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

Make sure you uncomment [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] annotation in webservice. Then I used this jquery/html (don't forget to reference jquery):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ type: 'POST', dataType: 'json', contentType: 'application/json', data: {} });

        $.ajax({
            url: 'Lookup.asmx/LoadUsers',
            data: '',
            success: function (data) {
                var responseJson = data.d; 
                if (responseJson.length > 0) {
                    $.each(responseJson, function () {
                        $("#result").append("<li><input type='checkbox'>" + this.Name + "</input></li>")                                    
                    });
                }
            }
        });



        $("#txtType").keyup(function () {
            var input = $(this).val();
            $("#result").html("");
            if (input && input.length > 3) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'Lookup.asmx/GetUsers',
                    data: '{ "query": "' + input + '" }',
                    success: function (data) {
                        var responseJson = data.d; 
                        if (responseJson.length > 0) {
                            $.each(responseJson, function () {
                                $("#result").append("<li><input type='checkbox'>" + this.Name + "</input></li>")                                    
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    });
</script>
<table cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
        <td>Search</td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtType" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>            
        <td colspan="2">
            <ul id="result" style="list-style: none;">
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then you can easily use jquery to see which checkboxes were checked.

Comment: Sorry, I've been a little busy and I just implemented the solution you gave and it works. The problem now it's that it loses its property on another textbox post back. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. Thanks a lot :)